# How can I determine whether a JuMP model solved by Gurobi is a MIP?

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

Suppose, I create a [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl) model, pass it to the solver and retrieve a solution. Now I want to determine whether the model solved by [Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/) (i.e. after presolve) was a mixed-integer program (MIP). I need this information since I would like to print the MIP gap (if it exists) of the solution. Obviously, it is not necessarily known in advance, if the JuMP model is in fact a MIP, or if all integer variables will be removed by presolve.

This code example creates a simple model (without any integer variables) and solves it:

```
import JuMP
import Gurobi

model = JuMP.Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)

JuMP.@variable(model, x)
JuMP.@constraint(model, x>=0)
JuMP.@objective(model, Min, x)

JuMP.optimize!(model)
```

If the problem were (even after presolve) a MIP, I could just use

```
mip_gap = JuMP.relative_gap(model)
```

to get the MIP gap. But in the above case (i.e. not a MIP), it triggers

> ERROR: Gurobi.GurobiError(10005, "Unable to retrieve attribute 'MIPGap'")

What does not work either is

```
mip_gap = JuMP.get_optimizer_attribute(model, "MIPGap")
```

because this returns the MIP gap which is used as a termination criterion (i.e. not the MIP gap of the actual solution).

I did not find any function within the source code of JuMP and [MathOptInterface](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/MathOptInterface.jl) that returns the MIP gap directly. However, Gurobi has a model attribute called [IsMIP](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/ismip.html), which should be accessible. But

```
is_mip = JuMP.get_optimizer_attribute(model, "IsMIP")
```

causes

> ERROR: LoadError: Unrecognized parameter name: IsMIP.

I also tried to find a solution within [Gurobi.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl) and discovered that the Gurobi parameter "IsMIP" is implemented [here](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/blob/master/src/MOI_wrapper.jl#L2984). There is also a function called [is_mip](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/blob/master/src/grb_attrs.jl#L411) that indeed does what I want. The problem is, that I can not use it because the argument has to be a Gurobi [Model](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/blob/master/src/grb_model.jl#L9), not a JuMP model.

What can I do?

Comment: What about using a try/catch construct to handle the failure to get the mipgap. If it fails, conclude it was likely not a mip.

Comment: I tried that but somehow the error is not catched and the execution stops anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So unfortunately, there are a couple of things going on that combine to make your issue.

1) JuMP's "optimizer attributes" correspond to Gurobi's "parameters." So you can only use `get/set_optimizer_attribute` to query things like tolerances. This is why you can query `MIPGap` (a Gurobi parameter), but not `IsMIP` (a Gurobi model attribute).

2) Not to worry, because you should be able to access Gurobi Model attributes (and variable/constraint attributes) as follows:

```
MOI.get(model, Gurobi.ModelAttribute("IsMIP"))
```

3) However, it seems there is a bug somewhere in the stack that means we are re-directing the call incorrectly as we try to go from JuMP to Gurobi. As a work-around, you can use

```
MOI.get(backend(model).optimizer, Gurobi.ModelAttribute("IsMIP"))
```

I've filed an issue so this gets fixed in a future release (https://github.com/JuliaOpt/MathOptInterface.jl/issues/1092).